# Get Class of Map in FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

I want to get a variable's class type in freemarker, used `var.class.simpleName`;
but if var is a Map, freemarker will process class as a key to find value in var.
it throw exception. how can I do this ? thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I solved it,should `setObjectWrapper` with BeansWrapper           Configuration config = new Configuration();
// config.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
config.setObjectWrapper(new BeansWrapper());

Comment: And so you have wrecked all usual `Map` lookups... In short, I wouldn't recommend this for anybody.

Answer (score 1):

First I have to ask why do you need that, because FreeMarker templates aren't supposed to know even if `var` is `Map` at all. Maybe your data-model is not what the template needs.

Anyway, for now, I would write a custom `TemplateMethodModelEx` for this purpose, something that you can use like `${classOf(var)}`. Inside the `TemplateMethodModelEx` implementation you will receive a `TemplateModel` as the argument value, and then you can check if it's an `AdapterTemplateModel`, and if so you can get back the original object and get its class. (If it's not a `AdapterTemplateModel`, then it perhaps isn't even a wrapped Java object, so it doesn't make sense to ask what the class of the original object is.) However, the `DefaultObjectWrapper` with `incompatibleImprovements` set to less than 2.3.22 doesn't give `AdapterTemplateModel` to wrapped `Map`-s... so in 2.3.21 you will still have to use `BeansWrapper`, but you can at least set `simpleMapWrapper` to `true`.

In 2.3.22 it will be actually possible to write `${var?api.class}`... you might use the nightly build. Though it only supposed to solve the problem where you can't access *business* methods because the primary type of the business class is `Map`.